# [Wifi Connection]Intel 12th gen 12900k + [ASUS] ROG STRIX Z690-A GAMING WIFI D4

Tags: networking, intel

I recently purchased [ASUS] ROG STRIX Z690-A GAMING WIFI D4 with Intel's new CPU, 12900k. However, after installing ubuntu 20.04, I'm not able to connect to Wi-Fi. It says "No Wi-Fi Adapter Found" but I thought the motherboard supports Wi-Fi connections as it has wifi in its product name. Please let me know how to fix this problem. THnks

Comment: Begin by [edit]ing your Question and show us `sudo lshw -C network`

Comment: A better command is `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3`