# Cannot Find Wifi Adapter ROG STRIX Z690-A GAMING WIFI D4

Tags: networking, dual-boot, drivers, 20.04

I am having similar issues to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1375877/wifi-connectionintel-12th-gen-12900k-asus-rog-strix-z690-a-gaming-wifi-d4). I have Googled around a great deal and tried many things, but I cannot seem to find a solution. I am currently dual booting Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04 on a custom built PC using a [ROG STRIX Z690-A Gaming Wifi D4](https://rog.asus.com/motherboards/rog-strix/rog-strix-z690-a-gaming-wifi-d4-model/spec), and the wifi adapter is working in the Windows partition but appears to be unfound in the Ubuntu partition.

I have downloaded the [drivers directly from Intel](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/wireless.html) for the Intel Wi-Fi 6 AX201, which is what I believe the Wifi module is.

I have tried using the backport-iwlwifi package.

I have disabled fastboot in Windows, in the BIOS, and disabled Windows from being able to turn off the wireless adapter and any networking adapter.

Here is the result of `sudo lshw -C network` on my system

```
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       version: 11
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: iomemory:400-3ff memory:401421c000-401421ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
       logical name: enp6s0
       version: 03
       serial: <redacted>
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=igc driverversion=5.11.0-41-generic latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:19 memory:85b00000-85bfffff memory:85c00000-85c03fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       bus info: usb@1:1
       logical name: usb0
       serial: <redacted>
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=5.11.0-41-generic firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.240.244 link=yes multicast=yes
```

And here is the result of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3`

```
00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:7af0] (rev 11)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Ethernet
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0074]
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:7acc] (rev 11)
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1379863/wifi-and-bluetooth-doesnt-work-for-intel-ax201-in-ubuntu-21-10 I recommend that you install 5.15 kernel version. https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.15/

Comment: Amazing, that's exactly what fixed it, thanks so much